# How can I get Wither skeletons to spawn?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm trying to get Wither skeleton skulls but I can't farm Wither skeletons because they won't spawn.

I am playing on Xbox 360 which means that there are very small worlds (less than 900x900) and there is one extremely small nether fortress. I spent hours looking but none have spawned.

How can I get them to spawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't have many options.

Usually you would have to wait for the Wither Skeletons to spawn, but there's a known bug for the Xbox (360) version of Minecraft.

If absolutely no Wither Skeletons spawn you should **reset your Nether**. This option can be found in the world selection menu (under world options).